# Install MariaDB 10 Generic Binaries + TokuDB

Tags: mariadb, tokudb

I used to install MariaDB from Generic Binaries on a Debian Wheezy 64bits:

**mariadb-10.0.13-linux-x86_64.tar.gz**
(from downloads.mariadb.org)

I would like to use TokuDB as Storage Engine.

However, TokuDB is available in "glibc_214" generic linux package as well as .deb packages, but it is NOT available in "non glibc_214 generic linux package"...

I can't use "mariadb-10.0.13-linux-glibc_214-x86_64.tar.gz" because Debian Wheezy glibc is 2.13:

```
$~: ldd --version
ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+deb7u4) 2.13
```

Why is TokuDB not available in standard 64bits version of Generic Binaries?

Is it safe to copy `ha_tokudb.so` from an debian wheezy apt install (/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_tokudb.so) to a generic linux "manual" installation (in ./lib/plugin)?

If I do so, I can enable TokuDB and all seems to work (I hope so anyway...):

```
(none)=# INSTALL SONAME 'ha_tokudb';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.30 sec)
(none)=# SHOW ENGINES;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                                    | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
...
| TokuDB             | YES     | Tokutek TokuDB Storage Engine with Fractal Tree(tm) Technology             | YES          | YES  | YES        |
...
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Have you considered installing from source?

Answer (score 1):

The right place to ask this question in by filing a ticket in the [MariaDB Jira](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa) or on the #mariadb IRC channel on freenode.

Comment: You're right. Thanks. I just opened a ticket on [Jira](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-6793)

Comment: But if you got the answer you were looking for, it would be nice if you add it here.